# What is the name or origin of this opening for Black?

Tags: opening, history

I was playing online, and I noticed some players go for this opening and I don't know its name or if it's a move order to another opening for Black.

```
[fen ""]
1. d4 g6 2. c4 Bg7 3. Nc3 c6 4. e4 d6 5. f3 Nbd7
```

Is it a sideline in the Modern, Kings Indian, Hippo, or Neo-old Benoni Defense? Or is it a new opening? In the Neo-old Benon,i Black doesn't fianchetto the bishop, and in the Hippo Black doesn't commit to c6 at an early stage like that.

Comment: It looks like a Modern Defense, Gurgendize variation, since Black hasn't played Nf6, but I am unable to find this exact position in my copies of MCO or ECO A or C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no name that I can find. However, I can identify some factors of this opening.

1. White has a Samisch setup
2. Black has played a type of Gurgendize modern defence.

Perhaps this opening is a move order in the Samisch where Black delays ...Nf6 and ...e5.